# Win32_SoundDevice from WMI not recognizing: RealTek(R) Audio (Headphones and microphone)

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, audio, wmi

I am trying to get the device of my headphones, which I connect to the 3.5 mm headphone jack.
On the other hand headphones connected via USB are being recognized.
Is there a way to access those audio devices through the Win32_SoundDevice query request or is that simply not possible and if so is there any
other way to get those?

In additon, I have the same problem with my wireless headphone/microphone.

Thank you a lot in advance!!!

PS: NAudio can't be used due to bad performance and "long" polling time to access the properties of MMDevices etc. Is there a way to get them efficiently?

Comment: Check you can see `Jack Mic (Realtek Audio)` under `Audio inputs and outputs` and `Realtek Audio` under `Sound, video and game controllers` in Device Manager. If you can see them use [this powershell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/86550b1a-bb3f-47c3-8056-bbd57e508b7a) to see if you can list it.